# how can I get the other controller's variable inside one controller in flutter using getx

Tags: flutter, oop, dart, flutter-getx

This is an issue related to the getx in flutter.
I have 2 controllers. ContractsController and NotificationController.
In ContractsController I have put the value into observer variable by calling the Api request.
What I want now is to get that variable's data in another controller - NotificationController.
How to get that value using getx functions?

ContractsController

```
class ContractsController extends GetxController {
  ExpiringContractRepository _expiringContractRepository;

  final expiringContracts = <ExpiringContract>[].obs; // This is the value what I want in another controller

  ContractsController() {
    _expiringContractRepository = new ExpiringContractRepository();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    await refreshContracts();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future refreshContracts({bool showMessage}) async {
    await getExpiringContracts();
    if (showMessage == true) {
      Get.showSnackbar(Ui.SuccessSnackBar(message: "List of expiring contracts refreshed successfully".tr));
    }
  }

  Future getExpiringContracts() async {
    try {
      expiringContracts.value = await _expiringContractRepository.getAll(); // put the value from the api
    } catch (e) {
      Get.showSnackbar(Ui.ErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

The expiringContracts is updated successfully with data after the api request.
Now, I want to get that value in NotificationController

NotificationController

```
class NotificationsController extends GetxController {
  final notifications = <Notification>[].obs;
  ContractsController contractsController;

  NotificationsController() {
  }

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    contractsController = Get.find<ContractsController>();
    print(contractsController.expiringContracts);  // This shows an empty list ?????  
    super.onInit();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some powerful approaches in GetX. I solved this issue with Get.put and Get.find

Here is the code that I added.

ContractsController

```
class ContractsController extends GetxController {
  ExpiringContractRepository _expiringContractRepository;

  final expiringContracts = <ExpiringContract>[].obs; // This is the value what I want in another controller

  ContractsController() {
    _expiringContractRepository = new ExpiringContractRepository();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    await refreshContracts();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future refreshContracts({bool showMessage}) async {
    await getExpiringContracts();
    if (showMessage == true) {
      Get.showSnackbar(Ui.SuccessSnackBar(message: "List of expiring contracts refreshed successfully".tr));
    }
  }

  Future getExpiringContracts() async {
    try {
      expiringContracts.value = await _expiringContractRepository.getAll(); // put the value from the API
      // ******************************** //
      Get.put(ContractsController()); // Added here
    } catch (e) {
      Get.showSnackbar(Ui.ErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

NotificationController

```
class NotificationsController extends GetxController {
  final notifications = <Notification>[].obs;
  ContractsController contractsController;

  NotificationsController() {
  }

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    // ******************************** //
    contractsController = Get.find<ContractsController>(); // Added here.
    print(contractsController.expiringContracts);  // This shows the updated value
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

Finally, I have found that GetX is simple but powerful for state management in flutter.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Denis, if this works for you, great.  One thing to check: is `ContractsController` removing itself from memory when you leave/pop the page that is calling `getExpiringContracts()`? (You'll see "ContractsController deleted from memory" message in your Debug or Run console if so.)

I ask since the controller is being registered inside `ContractsController`, which is a technique/idiom I've not seen before.

Comment: Hi. @Baker. Yes, I have just checked that on my app. Since the notification view will be routed from the contract view, this is working well, and there is no message that contractsController has been deleted. 
But when I leave from the notification view, it shows the controller deleted message.
Now, I understand that Get.put and find is available in the same stack route.
Thanks for your kind answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Overview

A couple solutions come to mind:

- pass the `expiringContracts` list as a constructor argument to `NotificationsController` if you only need this done once at instantiation, or
- use a GetX worker to update `NotificationsController` every time `expiringContracts` is updated

The first solution isn't related to GetX, rather it's just async coordination between `ContractsController` and `NotificationsController`, so lets focus on the 2nd solution: GetX Workers.

## Details

In `NotificationsController`, create a method that will receive `expiringContracts`.

Something like:

```
class NotificationsController extends GetxController {

  void refreshContracts(List<ExpiringContract> contracts) {
    // do something
  }

}
```

Please note: none of this code is tested.  I'm writing this purely in StackOverflow, so consider this pseudo-code.

In `ContractsController` we'll supply the above callback method as a constructor arg:

In `ContractsController`, something like:

```
class ContractsController {

  final expiringContracts = <ExpiringContract>[].obs

  final Function(List<ExpiringContract>) refreshContractsCallback;

  ContractsController(this.refreshContractsCallback);

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    refreshContracts();  // do your stuff after super.onInit
    ever(expiringContracts, refreshContractsCallback);
    // ↑ contracts → refreshContractsCallback(contracts)
    // when expiringContracts updates, run callback with them
  }
}
```

Here the GetX `ever` worker takes the observable as first argument, and a function as 2nd argument.  That function must take an argument of type that matches the observed variable, i.e. `List<ExpiringContract>`, hence the Type of `refreshContractsCallback` was defined as `Function(List<ExpiringContract>)`.

Now whenever the observable `expiringContracts` is updated in `ContractsController`, `refreshContractsCallback(contracts)` will be called, which supplies the list of expiring contracts to `NotificationsController` via `refreshContracts`.

Finally, when instantiating the two controllers [inside the `build()` method of your route/page](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/818#issuecomment-733652172):

```
NotificationsController nx = Get.put(NotificationsController());
ContractsController cx = Get.put(ContractsController(nx.refreshContracts));
```

#### Timeline of Events

- `NotificationsController` gets created as `nx`.
- `nx.onInit()` runs, slow call of `refreshContracts()` starts
- `ContractsController` gets created, with `nx.refreshContracts` callback
- your page paints

  - `nx` has no contracts data at this point, so you'll prob. need a `FutureBuilder` or an `Obx`/ `GetX` + `StatelessWidget` that'll rebuild when data eventually arrives
- when `refreshContracts()` finishes, `ever` worker runs, sending contracts to `nx`
- `nx.refreshContracts(contracts)` is run, doing something with contracts

**Notes**

- async/await was removed from `nx.onInit`
- `ever` worker will run when `refreshContract` finishes

Comment: Hi. @Baker. Thanks for your kind answer. That approach is a great one. Thanks. This is so helpful. Anyway, I solve this problem in another way. I will post my answer here, so do you have some time to check this?